# Chinese characters and Sweave: "invalid font type"

Tags: r, ggplot2, sweave

I can create a pie chart of Chinese provinces with the Chinese character labels correctly displayed using the following:

```
pie(table(df$provinces), family="STSong")
```

However, when I use Sweave to compile my PDF I get an "invalid font type" error. What's the most straightforward way to resolve this?
I'm running RStudio on Mac, and have tried playing around with library(extrafont) and loadfonts(), which seemed to resolve the error, but did not display the characters correctly in the final PDF.

I also tried using ggplot2 with the specification:

```
theme(axis.text=element_text(family="STSong"))
```

which again properly displays the Chinese in the RStudio Plots window, but when the final PDF is made the Chinese characters simply show up as dots.

Comment: Try compiling use `XeLaTeX`. You'll want to edit your preamble as well. [This blog post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/xelatex/) provides a nice starting place.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this small example using Sweave. It uses the [`showtext`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/showtext/index.html) package to handle Chinese fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
library(showtext)
showtext.begin()
plot(1, main = "中文")
showtext.end()
@

\end{document}
```

The point is to enclose your plotting functions within a pair of `showtext.begin()`/`showtext.end()` calls.